# Why are NLP processes considered language-dependent?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, sentiment-analysis

Why are NLP Processes considered language-dependent?

For example, here:
http://www.slideshare.net/saschanarr/languageindependent-twitter-sentiment-analysis
on slide 6, its says that: "Natural Language Processing methods are often designed specifically for one language".

Why is it so? I would think that once the method is implemented using machine learning, the algorithm is the same and all you need different is the training set...

Comment: Aren't there lots of heuristics and algorithms that would make sense in some languages but not others?  For instance, in English, I can do some processing based on word order in a sentence, e.g., distinguish between "John likes Mary" and "Mary likes John", whereas in Latin, the word order wouldn't be important, but the case of the names would be.  Not every approach for one language will work for another.

Comment: Yeah, but then it sounds like it's "only" heuristics, and that the core of the algorithm remains the same...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of heuristics, those are usually problem- and language-dependent. In the case of machine learning, yes, in an abstract, theoretical sense, the "only" difference is the training set. The availability of training sets for various languages is the first problem. Then comes the number of useful features that can be pruned from the training set, the availability of heuristics and knowledge sources to improve the machine learning, the hyperparameters required to make the learning successful, etc.

As an example, consider the problem of named-entity recognition (NER). On English data, the "word is capitalized" feature is almost a giveaway for spotting the names, but in German, every noun is capitalized. The result is that NER for German is quite a different problem than it is for English.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans . I'm looking for material about sentiment analysis, and I know that there are different sentiment analysis machines for different languages. Are you saying that the whole difference is in the heuristics?